# How to draw multiple lines with Google Charts

Tags: php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

The idea is to dynamically get the current month's, last month's and 2 month's back information about average download speeds which are stored in the mySQL database.

Database structure is:

```
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| Field     | Type      | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                         |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| ping      | float     | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| download  | float     | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| upload    | float     | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| date_time | timestamp | NO   |     | current_timestamp() | on update current_timestamp() |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
```

By following the instructions at https://maker.pro/raspberry-pi/tutorial/how-to-extract-and-chart-data-from-mysql I was able to chart one line. Then by trial/error I was able to include two other lines as well, but they are not treated as separate information but just an addition to the first one drawn to the same image.

I'm totally lost on how to loop the data for current month, then the month before and then the data from 2 months back so that the lines would have different color and would be easy to see if there has been any signifcant changes in the download speeds.

The code that outputs everything to one chart is as follows:

```
<?php

# Prepare a connection to the mySQL database
$connection = new mysqli("192.168.x.x", "username", "password", "dnbname");

# If there are any errors or the connection is not OK
if ($connection->connect_error) {
        die ('Connection error: '.$connection->connect_error);
}

# Prepare a query to the mySQL database and get average hourly based download speed this month
$sql = "select hour(date_time), round(avg(download),0) from results where MONTH(date_time) = MONTH(CURDATE()) group by hour(date_time);";
$result = $connection->query($sql);

# This while - loop formats and put all the retrieved data into ['timestamp', 'download'] way.
        $data1 = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data1[] = [$row['hour(date_time)'], $row['round(avg(download),0)']];
                }

# Prepare a query to the mySQL database and get average hourly based download speed last month
$sql2 = "select hour(date_time), round(avg(download),0) from results where DATE(date_time) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE
(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) group by hour(date_time);";
$result2 = $connection->query($sql2);

# This while - loop formats and put all the retrieved data into ['timestamp', 'download'] way.
        $data2 = array();
        while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data2[] = [$row['hour(date_time)'], $row['round(avg(download),0)']];
                }

# Prepare a query to the mySQL database and get average hourly based download speed 2 months ago
$sql3 = "select hour(date_time), round(avg(download),0) from results where DATE(date_time) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE
(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) group by hour(date_time);";
$result3 = $connection->query($sql3);

# This while - loop formats and put all the retrieved data into ['timestamp', 'download'] way.
        $data3 = array();
        while ($row = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data3[] = [$row['hour(date_time)'], $row['round(avg(download),0)']];
                }
?>
var data_currentmonth = <?php echo json_encode($data1); ?>;
var data_lastmonth = <?php echo json_encode($data2); ?>;
var data_monthb4lastmonth = <?php echo json_encode($data3); ?>;

<html>
<head>
<!-- start of the HTML part that Google Chart needs -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<!-- This loads the 'corechart' package. -->    
        <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']}).then(function drawChart() {
        
// Current month
        var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data1.addColumn({label: 'Hour', type: 'number'});
        data1.addColumn({label: 'Current months Avg.', type: 'number'});
        data1.addRows(data_currentmonth);

// Last Month
        var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data2.addColumn({label: 'Hour', type: 'number'});
        data2.addColumn({label: 'Last Months Avg.', type: 'number'});
        data2.addRows(data_lastmonth);

// Month Before Last Month
        var data3 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data3.addColumn({label: 'Hour', type: 'number'});
        data3.addColumn({label: 'Month Before Last Avg.', type: 'number'});
        data3.addRows(data_monthb4lastmonth);

// Join data tables
        var join1 = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0,0]], [1], [1]);
        var join2 = google.visualization.data.join(join1, data3, 'full', [[0,0]], [1,2], [1]);

//sort data
        join2.sort([
                {column: 0}
        ]);

// Curved line
var options = {
                title: '',
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' }
                };

// Curved chart
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
chart.draw(join2, options);

}); // End bracket from drawChart

</script>

<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 1800px; height: 960px;"></div>
```

Currently the image it outputs looks like this:
[image: output]

And here's some sample data:

var data_currentmonth = [["0","105"],["1","110"],["2","111"],["3","113"],["4","119"],["5","121"],["6","119"],["7","61"],["8","45"],["9","41"],["10","41"],["11","36"],["12","111"],["13","110"],["14","110"],["15","105"],["16","96"],["17","97"],["18","93"],["19","95"],["20","86"],["21","73"],["22","73"],["23","90"]];

var data_lastmonth = [["0","104"],["1","112"],["2","119"],["3","120"],["4","122"],["5","128"],["6","120"],["7","65"],["8","48"],["9","47"],["10","49"],["11","47"],["12","119"],["13","122"],["14","118"],["15","119"],["16","113"],["17","116"],["18","111"],["19","105"],["20","101"],["21","89"],["22","81"],["23","92"]];

var data_monthb4lastmonth = [["0","106"],["1","109"],["2","112"],["3","114"],["4","117"],["5","117"],["6","113"],["7","65"],["8","52"],["9","49"],["10","48"],["11","47"],["12","115"],["13","109"],["14","109"],["15","111"],["16","113"],["17","106"],["18","104"],["19","102"],["20","97"],["21","87"],["22","78"],["23","90"]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to draw multiple lines,
you'll multiple columns in the google data table.
and since you want to compare multiple months,
we can load multiple data tables, then join them together.

---

in the php, recommend building the full arrays in php,
then encoding them as json when adding to the script.
rather than using echo as strings.

see following php snippet...

```
<?php
  # If there are any errors or the connection is not OK
  if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die ('Connection error: '.$connection->connect_error);
  }

  # Prepare a query to the mySQL database and get average hourly based download speed this month
  $sql = "select hour(date_time), round(avg(download),0) from results where MONTH(date_time) = MONTH(CURDATE()) group by hour(date_time);";
  $result = $connection->query($sql);

  # This while - loop formats and put all the retrieved data into ['timestamp', 'download'] way.
  $data1 = array();
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data1[] = [$row['hour(date_time)'], $row['round(avg(download),0)']];
  }

  # Prepare a query to the mySQL database and get average hourly based download speed last month
  $sql2 = "select hour(date_time), round(avg(download),0) from results where DATE(date_time) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) group by hour(date_time);";
  $result2 = $connection->query($sql2);

  # This while - loop formats and put all the retrieved data into ['timestamp', 'download'] way.
  $data2 = array();
  while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data2[] = [$row['hour(date_time)'], $row['round(avg(download),0)']];
  }

  # Prepare a query to the mySQL database and get average hourly based download speed 2 months ago
  $sql3 = "select hour(date_time), round(avg(download),0) from results where DATE(date_time) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) group by hour(date_time);";
  $result3 = $connection->query($sql3);

  # This while - loop formats and put all the retrieved data into ['timestamp', 'download'] way.
  $data3 = array();
  while ($row = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data3[] = [$row['hour(date_time)'], $row['round(avg(download),0)']];
  }
?>

var data_month1 = <?php echo json_encode($data1); ?>;
var data_month2 = <?php echo json_encode($data2); ?>;
var data_month3 = <?php echo json_encode($data3); ?>;
```

then we can use the above month arrays to populate the google data table,
and draw the chart.
see following snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function drawChart() {

  // month 1
  var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data1.addColumn({label: 'Hour', type: 'number'});
  data1.addColumn({label: 'Month 1 Avg', type: 'number'});
  data1.addRows(data_month1);

  // month 2
  var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data2.addColumn({label: 'Hour', type: 'number'});
  data2.addColumn({label: 'Month 2 Avg', type: 'number'});
  data2.addRows(data_month2);

  // month 3
  var data3 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data3.addColumn({label: 'Hour', type: 'number'});
  data3.addColumn({label: 'Month 3 Avg', type: 'number'});
  data3.addRows(data_month3);

  // join data tables
  var join1 = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0,0]], [1], [1]);
  var join2 = google.visualization.data.join(join1, data3, 'full', [[0,0]], [1,2], [1]);

  // sort data
  join2.sort([
    {column: 0}
  ]);

  // Curved line
  var options = {
    title: '',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };

  // Curved chart
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
  chart.draw(join2, options);
}); // End bracket from drawChart
```

---

see following working snippet for an example of how the result could look...

```js
var data_month1 = [[1, 10],[2, 12],[3, 15],[4, 9],[5, 6]];
var data_month2 = [[1, 5],[2, 8],[3, 11],[4, 14],[5, 16]];
var data_month3 = [[1, 2],[2, 5],[3, 7],[4, 10],[5, 3]];

google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function drawChart() {

  // month 1
  var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data1.addColumn({label: 'Hour', type: 'number'});
  data1.addColumn({label: 'Month 1 Avg', type: 'number'});
  data1.addRows(data_month1);

  // month 2
  var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data2.addColumn({label: 'Hour', type: 'number'});
  data2.addColumn({label: 'Month 2 Avg', type: 'number'});
  data2.addRows(data_month2);

  // month 3
  var data3 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data3.addColumn({label: 'Hour', type: 'number'});
  data3.addColumn({label: 'Month 3 Avg', type: 'number'});
  data3.addRows(data_month3);

  // join data tables
  var join1 = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0,0]], [1], [1]);
  var join2 = google.visualization.data.join(join1, data3, 'full', [[0,0]], [1,2], [1]);

  // sort data
  join2.sort([
    {column: 0}
  ]);

  // Curved line
  var options = {
    title: '',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };

  // Curved chart
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
  chart.draw(join2, options);
}); // End bracket from drawChart
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="curve_chart"></div>
```

Comment: Getting there little by little. I got the output from the arrays OK, but the part where the graph should be drawn is blank. I really cannot put my finger what it actually is as there are some elements on the code you provided which I don't understand. Therefore finding the issue for me seems pretty tough...I updated the original code from my question to reflect current situation.

Comment: check the browser's console for errors (press F12) -- and it might help to share a sample of the data --> `console.log(JSON.stringify(data_currentmonth ));`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer, life got to way. The error is: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: data_currentmonth is not defined
    drawChart http://hdserver/dna/dna.php:20
    promise callback* http://hdserver/dna/dna.php:14

Comment: ok, so that means you're trying to use `data_currentmonth` as a variable in the javascript. but the variable is not defined anywhere. (`var data_currentmonth;`)  -- in the code I posted, I had used `data_month1`, `data_month2`, & `data_month3` --> `var data_month1 = <?php echo json_encode($data1); ?>;` -- so I might have messed you up there. just make sure whatever you use to store the data from php, is also used to load the chart data...

Comment: Yay, I feel stupid. Defining the variables was not "inside" the javascript. I must have looked at the about 50 times and could not see it. Well that's better now, but it seems that my data in the array is having double quotes (i.e "0", "100") around them, meaning they are not interpreted as numbers but as strings. Tried to play around with parseInt() function but was not able to convert the data (exampled above) to numbers. Should it be done in some type of loop in the code for all the data stored in the arrays?

Comment: there are a number of ways, but let's start with the easiest. try adding the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` argument to `json_encode` --> `var data_month1 = <?php echo json_encode($data1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full working code:

```
<?php

# Prepare a connection to the mySQL database
$connection = new mysqli("192.168.x.x", "username", "password", "dbname");

# If there are any errors or the connection is not OK
if ($connection->connect_error) {
        die ('Connection error: '.$connection->connect_error);
}

# Prepare a query to the mySQL database and get average hourly based download speed this month
$sql = "select hour(date_time), round(avg(download),0) from results where MONTH(date_time) = MONTH(CURDATE()) group by hour(date_time);";
$result = $connection->query($sql);

# This while - loop formats and put all the retrieved data into ['timestamp', 'download'] way.
        $data1 = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data1[] = [$row['hour(date_time)'], $row['round(avg(download),0)']];
                }

# Prepare a query to the mySQL database and get average hourly based download speed last month
$sql2 = "select hour(date_time), round(avg(download),0) from results where DATE(date_time) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) group by hour(date_time);";
$result2 = $connection->query($sql2);

# This while - loop formats and put all the retrieved data into ['timestamp', 'download'] way.
        $data2 = array();
        while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data2[] = [$row['hour(date_time)'], $row['round(avg(download),0)']];
                }

# Prepare a query to the mySQL database and get average hourly based download speed 2 months ago
$sql3 = "select hour(date_time), round(avg(download),0) from results where DATE(date_time) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) group by hour(date_time);";
$result3 = $connection->query($sql3);

# This while - loop formats and put all the retrieved data into ['timestamp', 'download'] way.
        $data3 = array();
        while ($row = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data3[] = [$row['hour(date_time)'], $row['round(avg(download),0)']];
                }
?>

<html>
<head>

<!-- start of the HTML part that Google Chart needs -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<!-- This loads the 'corechart' package. -->    
        <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']}).then(function drawChart() {

        
var data_currentmonth = <?php echo json_encode($data1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
var data_lastmonth = <?php echo json_encode($data2,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
var data_monthb4lastmonth = <?php echo json_encode($data3,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;

// Current month
        var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data1.addColumn({label: 'Hour', type: 'number'});
        data1.addColumn({label: 'Current Month Avg.', type: 'number'});
        data1.addRows(data_currentmonth);

// Last Month
        var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data2.addColumn({label: 'Hour', type: 'number'});
        data2.addColumn({label: 'Last Month Avg.', type: 'number'});
        data2.addRows(data_lastmonth);

// Month Before Last Month
        var data3 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data3.addColumn({label: 'Hour', type: 'number'});
        data3.addColumn({label: 'Month Before Last Avg.', type: 'number'});
        data3.addRows(data_monthb4lastmonth);

// Join data tables
        var join1 = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0,0]], [1], [1]);
        var join2 = google.visualization.data.join(join1, data3, 'full', [[0,0]], [1,2], [1]);

//sort data
        join2.sort([
                {column: 0}
        ]);

        
// Curved line
var options = {
                title: '',
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' }
                };

// Curved chart
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
chart.draw(join2, options);

}); // End bracket from drawChart
</script>

<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 1800px; height: 960px;"></div>
```

This creates image with 3 lines in different colors.
Now it's very easy for me to follow how my 4G connection download speeds are developing over the time.
The "funny" drop between 07:00-12:00 is because the operator has decreased the transmit power due to escavators working near the base station.